# pytest mock SQLAlchemy session.add_all() and session.commit()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am new in unittest and writing test with pytest. I have func:

```
def change_status(something):
    with context_session() as session:
        # Make something with something
        session.add_all()
        session.commit()
    return something
```

And  my test:

```
def test_change_statuses(self, mocker: MockFixture):
    with context_session() as session:
        mocker.patch.object(session, 'add_all')
        mocker.patch.object(session, 'commit')

        result = change_status(something)

    assert isinstance(result, tuple)
    assert isinstance(result[0], int)
```

My test run with real data in DB, but I do not wanna add_all and commit(). How can I do this?